# How to create a MemberExpression for List<string>, for Expression<Func<T,bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Following is my code to get a `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, which helps in providing the `Func<T,bool>`, for a list filtering, now for that I need to create a `MemberExpression` as follows (In code):

```
 MemberExpression memberExpressionColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType,"X");
```

Where `X` is the name of property meant for filtering, so when I am applying it on a `List<Person>`, it is easy to replace `X` with property `Name`, **but when I use the `List<string>` as source, then how to create `MemberExpression`, which is leading to Exception**

```
void Main()
{
    List<Person> personList = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person{ Name = "Shekhar", Age = 31},
            new Person{ Name = "Sandip", Age = 32},
            new Person{ Name = "Pramod", Age = 32},
            new Person{ Name = "Kunal", Age = 33}
        };


    var personNameList = personList.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

    var personNameHashset = new HashSet<string>(personNameList);

    var nameList = new List<string>() { "Kunal", "Pramod", "Mrinal" };

    var finalExpression = personNameHashset.EqualExpression<string>("Name");

    var finalFunc = finalExpression.Compile();

    var result = nameList.Where(finalFunc);

    result.Dump();
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static class ExpressionTreesExtension
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> EqualExpression<T>(this HashSet<string> nameHashSet, string columnName)
    {
        var expressionList = new List<Expression>();

        ParameterExpression parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");

        // Exception Here - How to create MemberExpression for primitive type list List<string>

        MemberExpression memberExpressionColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType,columnName);

        var containsMethodInfo = typeof(StringListExtensions).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(HashSet<string>) });

        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(nameHashSet, typeof(HashSet<string>));

        var resultExpression = Expression.Call(null, containsMethodInfo, memberExpressionColumn, constant);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(resultExpression, parameterType);
    }
}

public static class StringListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// String Extension - Contains (Substring)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="subString"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool Contains(this string name, HashSet<string> nameHashSet)
    {
        return nameHashSet.Contains(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need to get result like this:

```
var result = nameList.Where(obj => personNameHashset.Contains(obj));
```

Since you don't need to get `Name` property from the string you shouldn't use `memberExpressionColumn` and you can call `containsMethodInfo` with `ParameterExpression parameterType`. You can simplify your method to get `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` like this

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> EqualExpression<T>(this HashSet<string> nameHashSet)
{
    ParameterExpression parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
    var containsMethodInfo = typeof(StringListExtensions).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(HashSet<string>) });
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(nameHashSet, typeof(HashSet<string>));
    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(null, containsMethodInfo, parameterType, constant);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(resultExpression, parameterType);
}
```

and call it:

```
var finalExpression = personNameHashset.EqualExpression<string>();
var finalFunc = finalExpression.Compile();
var result = nameList.Where(finalFunc);
```